# Rails: conditional image link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the code below, @carousel is a collection of CarouselImages.  If the first CarouselImage has a populated "link_to" field, a picture link is displayed, otherwise the picture is displayed without a link.

```
<% if @carousel.first.link_to && @carousel.first.link_to <> "" %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(@carousel.first.image, class: "main-image",
      data: {image_id: @carousel.first.id,
        slide_no: 0, active: "true"}), @carousel.first.link_to %>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag(@carousel.first.image, class: "main-image",
      data: {image_id: @carousel.first.id,
        slide_no: 0, active: "true"}) %>
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to DRY this out and, if so, how?

Comment: Create a helper method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% img_tag = image_tag(@carousel.first.image, class: "main-image",
     data: {image_id: @carousel.first.id,
     slide_no: 0, active: "true"}) %>
<% if @carousel.first.link_to && @carousel.first.link_to != "" %>
  <%= link_to img_tag, @carousel.first.link_to %>
<% else %>
  <%= img_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You should not define methods in views

Comment: Did you downvote the *question* as well?  Do you actually know *why* you shouldn't define methods in views?

Comment: "Did you downvote the question as well?" no "Do you actually know why you shouldn't define methods in views?" yes

Comment: You could use a variable instead of a method: `img_tag = image_tag(...)`. This would be reasonable if you only need this in exactly one place and you don't want to move it off to some helper way off somewhere else.

Comment: @mu that's exactly what I tried before posting the question as I assumed the image_tag method just produced a load of html text, but for some reason it didn't work. And yes, I don't want to use a helper method for the reason you've given.

Comment: What exactly did you try and what does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: @muistooshort I've just tried replacing def img_tag with img_tag = and it worked fine now.  There must have been some other error in my code.  I've updated my answer to reflect this; I hope that's ok as technically it's really your answer now...

Comment: I'm cool with that. Don't forget that you can also accept your own answer.

Comment: @mu Thanks.  Just have to wait until tomorrow to accept.